# Error in importing table from teradata to hive using teradata-connector

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, teradata

I am trying to import `myemp` table from Teradata to hive using the `teradata-connector` and same error occurs for `hortonworks-teradata-connector` but it 
works well without using connectors by using JDBC.

```
hadoop com.teradata.hadoop.tool.TeradataImportTool \
-libjars $LIB_JARS \
-url jdbc:teradata://192.168.2.129/database=mydb \
-username kd \
-password exa \
-classname com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver \
-jobtype hive \
-fileformat rcfile \
-targettable tab1 \
-sourcetable myemp
```

Error:

```
16/10/20 11:10:17 INFO tool.ConnectorImportTool: ConnectorImportTool starts at 1476961817658
16/10/20 11:10:19 INFO common.ConnectorPlugin: load plugins in jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/sqoop/lib/teradata-connector-1.4.1-hadoop2.jar!/teradata.connector.plugins.xml
16/10/20 11:10:19 INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://sandbox.hortonworks.com:9083
16/10/20 11:10:19 INFO tool.ConnectorImportTool: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShims.getUGIForConf(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation;
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:292)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:103)
at com.teradata.connector.hive.utils.HiveUtils.isHiveOutputTablePartitioned(HiveUtils.java:1075)
at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorImportTool.processArgs(ConnectorImportTool.java:625)
at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorImportTool.run(ConnectorImportTool.java:58)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
at com.teradata.hadoop.tool.TeradataImportTool.main(TeradataImportTool.java:29)

16/10/20 11:10:19 INFO tool.ConnectorImportTool: job completed with exit code 10000
```

Comment: I edited the formatting, it was almost imposible to read. I would also suggest you provide some more information, an error log is usually not enough, try, for example, to explain what are you trying to do. The more information you give, the better people will be able to help you.

Comment: [This](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/17005/pig-and-hive.html) should help you!